# VS2010 unicode support gone after installing Service Pack 1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unicode, service-pack

I'm in a bit of a mess. I made the mistake of installing SP1 for VS2010 during development phase and now I'm in trouble. I'm working on a bengali website that has bengali unicode text hardcoded in many of the asp.net pages. Before installing SP1 everything was fine and I was able to see the unicode characters but now all I see is rectangle boxes!! I uninstalled SP1 but that didn't solve the problem either.

Any other idea's??

Answer (score 0):

Change the font to one that supports Bengali.
That is what boxes usually means: the characters are there, but the font does not have the necessary glyphs.